# Select row with Max column value: Managed to return correct answer but looking for cleaner imlementation

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max, inner-join

I have two tables `book(isbn, title, authorID, genre, pubYear, publisher,
rrPrice, avgRating)` and `orderDetails(oNo, bookISBN, quantity)`. There are multiple orders with their own orderDetails, therefore each book can have multiple orderDetails associated with them with their own quantity. I need to find the book(s) that have the most orders. I have managed to get the correct output but my solution is quite messy, involving using the same subquery twice and I was wondering if anyone could suggest a cleaner implementation? The answer I came up with is below:

```
SELECT title, pubYear, orderSum
FROM
(
SELECT title, pubYear,orderSum
FROM 
(
SELECT title, pubYear,SUM(quantity) AS orderSum
FROM book INNER JOIN orderDetails ON bookISBN = isbn
GROUP BY title, pubYear) T
GROUP BY title, pubYear) S
WHERE S.orderSum = (select max(S.orderSum) from (SELECT title, 
pubYear,orderSum
FROM 
(
SELECT title, pubYear,SUM(quantity) AS orderSum
FROM book INNER JOIN orderDetails ON bookISBN = isbn
GROUP BY title, pubYear) T
GROUP BY title, pubYear) S);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "simplest" form would use window functions -- but these are only available in MySQL 8+.

In older versions, you can phrase this as:

```
SELECT b.title, b.pubYear, SUM(od.quantity) AS orderSum
FROM book b INNER JOIN
     orderDetails od
     ON od.bookISBN = b.isbn
GROUP BY b.title, b.pubYear, b.isbn
HAVING SUM(od.quantity) = (SELECT SUM(od2.quantity)
                           FROM orderDetails od2
                           WHERE od2.isbn = b.isbn
                           ORDER BY SUM(od2.quantity DESC)
                          );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about solving the problem.

SELECT b.title, `b.pubYear`, Count(o.bIsbn) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM books AS b INNER JOIN OrderDetails as o ON b.bIsbn = o.bIsbn
GROUP BY b.title, b.pubYear
ORDER BY NumberOfOrders DESC